# Left join sum, group trouble

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT
  `from_id` as user_id,
  MAX(`createdon`) as updated_at,
  SUM(`unread`) as new,
  u.username,
  p.sessionid,
  s.access
FROM (
   SELECT `from_id`, `createdon`, `unread`
   FROM `modx_messenger_messages`
   WHERE `to_id` = {$id}
   UNION 
   SELECT `to_id`, `createdon`, 0
   FROM `modx_messenger_messages`
   WHERE `from_id` = {$id}
   ORDER BY `createdon` DESC
) as m
LEFT JOIN `modx_users` as u ON (u.id = m.from_id)
LEFT JOIN `modx_user_attributes` as p ON (p.internalKey = m.from_id)
LEFT JOIN `modx_session` as s ON (s.id = p.internalKey)
GROUP BY `from_id`
ORDER BY `new` DESC, `createdon` DESC;
```

table

```
id | message | createdon | from_id | to_id | unread   
1  | test    | NULL      |   5     |    6  |   0
2  | test2   | NULL      |   6     |    5  |   1
3  | test3   | NULL      |   6     |    5  |   1
```

result `new` = 28. Why?
If remove joins `new` = 2, correctly.

Comment: We don't have access to the data in your tables, so we would have no idea what the computation should yield.

Comment: You cannot show a data set comprising of one table, and a query comprising of four tables and expect us to make anything meaningful out of it.

Comment: Most likely you need to do the aggregation in a separate query and then `join` those results to the other tables.  As is, you're duplicating results with the joins (or at least that's the best guess given your post).  Also, be careful with that type of `group by` -- mysql allows it, but most databases do not and this could return some random results.

Answer (score 0):

Though it depends on the actual database, pure SQL says that a statement using GROUP BY requires all non-aggregated columns to be in the GROUP BY.  Without including all columns, weird stuff can happen, which might explain why you get different results.  If you know that the other columns are going to be the same within the user_id, you could do MAX(u.username) or something similar (again, depending on your database server).  So I'd try and clean up the SQL statement first.